# Apache CXF Webservice failing on AJAX call

Tags: ajax, web-services, cxf

We have developed a webservice based on `Apache CXF`.

This is working fine when accessed normally that is using `APIGEE` or by using a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` (A clinet for `Apache CXF`). But when I tried to access this by providing the SOAP Address through AJAX call it is giving me the following exception:

```
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /tata-ws-1.0/TataWeb)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.URIMappingInterceptor.handleMessage(URIMappingInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:89)
        ...
```

This is my AJAX call code happens on click of a button

```
<a onclick="sendRequest('GET','http://localhost:8080/tata-ws-1.0/services/TataWeb')"href="#">
```

Get Data:

```
function sendRequest(method, url)
{
    method == 'POST';
    {
        http.open(method,url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send(null);
    }
}
```

The URL for WSDL  is correct because when i use 
`http://localhost:8080/tata-ws-1.0/services/TataWeb?wsdl` it shows the WSDL for that webservice.

Please share your inputs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to send a SOAP request rather than a regular HTTP request.
Best way would be use something like this:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient