# Get username and password from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, cxf

I need to get username and password from `HttpServletRequest` to process the basic authentication. What I have is `CXF` endpoint and the basic auth interceptor. The `HttpServletRequest` I get like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message)            
        throws Fault {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST); 

}
```

When I tried to debug the code and I see that:

```
request.getAuthType() is null
request.getRemoteUser() is null
```

The username and password I am sending with the request from Soap UI. So the question is how am I able to get the username and password from the request?

**EDIT**

Header looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8011/GradIrelandUserRegistration HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: Basic UGF1bGl1czpQYXVsaXVzMTIz
Content-Length: 3170
Host: localhost:8011
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

They say that Authorization is basic, but then why call `request.getAuthType()` is returning null?

Comment: Have you checked the headers or parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out my self. In Soap UI I needed to change the Authentication type to:

```
Preemptive
```

and then use:

```
AuthorizationPolicy policy = (AuthorizationPolicy) message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName());
```

From the policy object now I am able to get the username and password.

Comment: I would when I can. Only in two days :D

Comment: Read This For Why :http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer .. :D

Answer (score 0):

[This may be helpful to you](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/http-binding.html) 
.
I'm bit new in SOAP data parsing so, if not working then let me know brief problem.
.
Also Check this  [J-Query Plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient)  for parsing SOAP services with the database. check this  [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512262/1557322)